# unable to interpret IE conditionals in this <head> snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Could somebody help me out read this?

```
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

I understand that if current browser is greater than ie 8, we end up using the 1.9.1 and if current browser is less than or equal to 8, we end up with 1.7.2

I've got a few questions here;

First one is what if the browser is not even IE? Chrome for example. 
How does the above header code gets to include JQuery at all. Obviously it does, but can't see how. Condition is only addressing IE. Isn't it?

Secondly, I am confused on the snytax; 
`<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->` part looks different than `<!--[if lte IE 8]>` part. the extra `<!-->` in the former confuses me.

Here is where I got the snippet from; 
http://bombdiggitydesign.com/crisp-2/Crisp-cool/index.html

It somehow loads the JQuery for me ( I'm using Chrome ). 
When I examine the `viewsource:`, I see this

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
```

and in this, only the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js is clickable in chrome's view. So, chrome somehow makes it thru the `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->` condition.

Obviously, it works but I am confused as to how.

Answer (score 2):

For your fist question, that's the specialty of [IE conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment).

For your sencond question,

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> //COMMENTS ENDS
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/>    
<!--<![endif]--> //COMMENTS ENDS
```

This is nothing just comments for their convenience (to be precise READABILITY).  *But the jQuery 1.9.1 will work in all browsers*.

However your **jQuery 1.9.1** *will be overridden by the jQuery 1.7.2, only in IE <=7 browsers*.

**FYI:** In Internet Explorer 10 HTML conditional comments are not supported when the page is in standards mode (document mode 10)

Hope you understand.

Comment: Comment ends! Thank you! That explains how chrome gets to see it. Obviously the theme's HTML is broken! I will contact the person to fix it in her premium theme.

Comment: @AverageJoe Glad to hear it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Those conditionals are wrong, that's why. Go here to see how they should be structured: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong "IE Hacks", so your code is invaild.
Here is an article that will help you out:

[To Article](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks)

Answer (score 1):

conditional comments are ms proprietary markup...so only trident (ie) will read conditional comments....and that's only up to ie10...although you can still use conditional compilation.

idk the exacts about how/what other engines do when they come across them...you're saying chrome sees them...i guess that makes sense...as long as no one is rendering/do anything to it, except for the browsers you are targeting with it.

you're conditional statements are invalid, as the other two gents have pointed out. if you correct the syntax, they'll work just fine.